# is it possible to push a git repository to a folder of another repo (for example, github pages)?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a git repository - lets call it A, with a remote on github. I have another repo - B.

Is it possible to set up a way to push A into a subfolder in B?

For example, I have a project written in html/js/css. I want to have this project in a standalone github repo, as well as host in on my github pages repo, in a subdirectory (for example, as broshen.github.io/project/index.html)

How would I set this up?

Comment: You can use git submodule. Add  project `A` as a submodule of project `B`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add A as a submodule in repo B, but you'll need to commit a submodule update in B any time you want to deploy your changes.

Since you mentioned `broshen.github.io/project/index.html`, it seems worth mentioning that you can add a `gh-pages` branch (or configure it to use `docs/`) to automatically deploy to `username.github.io/reponame/` (e.g. https://dahlbyk.github.io/posh-git/ deployed from [`gh-pages`](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/tree/gh-pages)).

Comment: oh, neat! I ended up going with the github pages solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add Project `A` as a submodule of project `B`.

```
# go into project 'B'
$ git submodule add <repo-A-url>
$ git submodule init              # intitialize the submodule
$ git submodule update            # update all the changes/commits of submodule
```

[More Submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: [Pro Git book has a chapter on submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).